# CSS - Navigation container stretching when hovering over link with smaller text

Tags: css

I've added a new link to my navigation bar, and for more visibility, have added a "New" marker to this link for improved visibility. This "New" marker is 0.8rem compared to the link's text being 1rem. I mention this because if the "New" marker is changed to be 1rem, then this issue does not occur.

**The issue itself**:
When hovering over the "Order Now" link (see Codepen), you might notice that the container height is stretched by maybe a pixel or 2 from the bottom - it's somewhat hard to see in this example but tried to make the colours as obvious as possible. It's most obvious when looking at the blue underline that there is a small gap between the active link (About us) and the hovered link. This only happens when hovering over "Order Now", and as mentioned, is rectified when setting the font size of "New" to 1rem (or removing "New" completely)

**Codepen with minimum example**: https://codepen.io/ftahir192/pen/PoPXjEv

This is the css for the "New" marker:

```
.new-marker {
    color: red;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

There's nothing special going on with that aside from the differing font size. I've tried:

- Setting absolute positions on the container
- Setting relative positions on the links itself
- Playing with line-height - this fixes it but seems more of a hack.

It's a minor nuisance but still a nuisance nonetheless and something I haven't been able to get to the bottom of. Any tips would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix that by adding `line-height` its not a hack, the `<i>` tag inherits the `<a>` tag line-height attribute value (which is `60px`), line height will fix it for you:

```
.new-marker {
  color: red;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  line-height:1rem;
}
```

Comment: This has fixed it, thanks! Can you explain a little more what was happening here?

Comment: basically the `<i>` tag inside `<a>`, so its the `<a>` child, any attribute you give to the parent tag will be applied to the child element unless you provide an CSS to override it, the `<a>` tag have a `line-height:60px`, the `<i>` will have this attribute along with `font-size` you provided, this is why it have an extra `1px`, all you need to do is to give it a line height smaller than the parent, [read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance) I hoe I explained it well :)

Answer (score 0):

setting the `min-height:70px` is the reason for this issue. My suggestion is you should change to `height: 91px` or any other hardcoded value. and avoid using `min-height`.

Comment: Setting the height to 91px fixes the described issue but introduces a similar issue whereby the top of the border for "Order Online" when hovered is cut off by a pixel. So instead of it being stretched like previously, it just takes a pixel of height off the border. It's harder to notice though

Comment: Add `line-height:50px;` to the marker this will work i think